# Firebase Javascript check if storage exist before running function

Tags: javascript, firebase

is there a way to check if the storage first exists before firing the getDownloadURL option?

Here is my code.

```
var storagedpurl = firebase.storage().ref(firebaseUser.uid + '/profilePicture/' + "displaypicture"); //URL to get current user dp
storagedpurl.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) { //Download dp from storage and display in circle img tag
  var firebaseimageurl = url;
  document.querySelector('img').src = firebaseimageurl;
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error.code);
});
```

[image]

In the case where I do not have the storage folder for profilepicture, my console log will keep showing the error that says I do not have the storage object. Therefore I'd like it to only run the function if the storage object exists, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

You have to **download to check**, if it exists or not. [Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) responds with proper error telling you why it failed.

Use the `catch` block to handle errors:

```
.catch(function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'storage/object_not_found': // <<< here you decide what to do when the file doesn't exist
      // File doesn't exist
      break;

    case 'storage/unauthorized':
      // User doesn't have permission to access the object
      break;

    case 'storage/canceled':
      // User canceled the upload
      break;

    ...

    case 'storage/unknown':
      // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
      break;
  }
});
```

A full list of error codes is available [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors).

Comment: Ah I see, is there a way to hide the error from showing in the console of my browser?

Comment: You are writing it in the console, see your catch block. Remove that line and it won't appear.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean my console.log error. I've edited my post to show a screenshot of the error that keeps popping up in the console, do have a look. I'd like to hide this or prevent it from showing up

Comment: You're assigning `firebaseurl` to your image tag named `img`. The error will appear when browser will fail to get the image from that URL you assigned to `img.src`. Now you either remove the `src` on error, or hide the `img` element. But I recommend letting the error in the console, it doesn't harm you.

Comment: Ah i see, sorry I'm new to website programming. But wouldn't it be dangerous if any users come across this error and they can to click to view my codes from the error?

Comment: No, you don't put anything secret or secure in the frontend javascript code. Go to the browser's **sources** tab and you will find entire code of yours :) The point is, everything in browser can be seen and read. You put the secure code at server, and public code and public keys at client side.

Comment: I understand now! Thanks alot Shaharyar! :)

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, the firebase storage designed in a way that the users request a file that only exists. Therefore non-existing file have to handled as error

[See this documentation for how to handle this errors in storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors)

Otherwise, I would suggest you can use [getDownloadUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors). which in turn returns a promise like below,

```
storageRef.child("file.png").getDownloadURL().then(onResolve, onReject);
function onResolve(foundURL) {
   //stuff
}
function onReject(error) {
   console.log(error.code);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to hide in the console. In your catch function remove console.log and use the switch statement mentioned by Shaharyar in below

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what happens, please have a look.

Comment: can you show the full console log error? you have cropped it so I can't see, from where it's printed if you could please show me the entire console.log screenshot

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. What I mean by the error, is exactly what is shown in the picture. I'd like to remove this error from being shown in the console. Not the console.log error

Comment: Sorry, I want to see the full screenshot of console.

Comment: I've added it in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154004/discussion-between-murugan-and-learning2code).